# python - web2py - can't seem to find lxml - ActivePython - windows7

Tags: python, lxml, web2py, activepython

Have been using ActivePython on windows7 and lxml seems working without an issue..
There were a lot of other third party packages I had & they were working too..

Until I wanted to use it inside **Web2Py**.

All the others seem to be working if I copy them directly inside `c:/web2py/applications/myApp/modules`

With lxml, seems I need to copy something else..

I have a third party module, which imports lxml like this : `from lxml.etree import tostring`

It ends up throwing - `No module named lxml.etree`

My test program outside web2py runs without an issue with both these modules.
When I do a `pypm files lxml` I see this :
`%APPDATA%\Python\Python27\site-packages\lxml-2.3-py2.7.egg-info`

What else should I copy along with the lxml directory into the `modules` directory ?

Pretty sure it's me doing something wrong instead of Web2py, but can't put a finger on..

web2py version = **Version 1.99.7 (2012-03-04 22:12:08) stable**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the Windows binary version of web2py, it comes with its own Python 2.5 interpreter and is self-contained, so it won't use your system's Python 2.7 nor see any of its modules. Instead, you should switch to running web2py from source. It's just as easy as the binary version -- just download the zip file and unzip it. You can then import lxml without moving anything to the application's /modules folder.

Comment: No wonder I kept seeing references to 2.5.2 & the python2.5.dll !!!! Let me try that !